# How to return ordinary variables from scipy odeint?

Tags: python, r, scipy, ode

I have an R code, solving an ordinary differential equation using ode function from DeSolve package.

```r
f <- function(t, y, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(y, parms)),{
    rate <- M * A/(A + K) * A
    
    dA <- -rate + D * (IN - A)
    dB <- rate - D * B
    
    Total <- A + B
    
    Conserved<- dA + dB - D * (IN - A) + D * B
    
    return (list(c(dA, dB),
                 Total = Total, rate = rate, Conserved = Conserved))
  })
}
```

I want to replicate this code in python, however, I cannot figure out how can I return also values of ordinary variables such as `Total`, `rate`, and `Conserved`.
Right now, I'm recalculating everything after the integration, as in the code below, but I'm not sure how to recalculate the variable `Conserved`.

```
def f(C0, t):
    A, B = C0
    rate = M*A/(A+K)*B
    dA = - rate + D*(IN-A)
    dB = rate - D*B
    return [dA, dB]

times = np.arange(0, 0.05*365, 0.005)

C = odeint(f, C0, times)

DF = pd.DataFrame(C, columns=['A', 'B'])
DF['time'] = times
DF['Total'] = DF['A'] + DF['B']
DF['rate'] = M*DF['A']/(DF['A']+K)*DF['B']
```

Could you help me with converting this R code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `odeint` does not support the output of internal variables directly, but it is possible to emulate the behavior.

### Python

First create a function `f2` with all desired variables. For sake of simplicity, let's also output time `t` and both the derivatives `dA`, `dB` and the states `A`, `B`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def f2(C0, t):
    A, B = C0
    rate = M*A/(A+K) * A
    dA = - rate + D * (IN - A)
    dB =   rate - D * B
    Total = A + B
    Conserved = dA + dB - D * (IN - A) + D * B
    return [t, dA, dB, A, B, Total, rate, Conserved]
```

Now create a function `f` that returns only the derivatives:

```
def f(C0, t):
  x = f2(C0, t)
  return(x[1], x[2])
```

We need also some time steps, initial variables and parameters. As the OP did not provide values, let's set it to arbitrary values, e.g. 1.0:

```
times = np.arange(0, 0.05*365, 0.005)
C0 = 1, 1
D  = 1
K  = 1
IN = 1
M  = 1
```

Now we solve the model `f` with `odeint`:

```
C  = odeint(f, C0, times)
```

Finally, we run the full function with all internal variables in a loop with the results of `odeint` instead of `C0`.

```
ret = [None] * len(C)

for i in np.arange(1, len(C)):
  ret[i] = f2(C[i], times[i])

# last row of the result
ret[len(C)-1]
```

The procedure is essentially how R's `deSolve::ode` handles this internally. First it integrates the ode system and then it runs a second pass with the integrated states to get the internal variables.

### R

Here for comparison a full R code:

```r
library(deSolve)

f <- function(t, y, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(y, parms)),{
    rate <- M * A/(A + K) * A
    dA <- -rate + D * (IN - A)
    dB <- rate - D * B
    Total <- A + B
    Conserved <- dA + dB - D * (IN - A) + D * B
    return (list(c(dA, dB),
                 Total = Total, rate = rate, Conserved = Conserved))
  })
}

times <- seq(0, 0.05*365, 0.005)
parms <- c(D=1, K=1, IN=1, M=1)
y0 <- c(A=1, B=1)

out <- ode(y0, times = times, f, parms)
tail(out, 1)
```